# ¿Cómo cerrar al mismo tiempo varias terminales ejecutadas desde un mismo script?

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell-script

Tengo un **Script en bash** que lanza 4 terminales y quisiera cerrarlas juntas al finalizar el objetivo productivo del programa.

Para este proyecto he revisado la siguiente documentación:

> OFICIAL
>
> - [man xfce-4](https://man.cx/xfce4-terminal(1))
> - [man kill](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html)
>
> COMUNIDAD
>
> - Como capturar el valor de [PID](https://qastack.mx/unix/30370/how-to-get-the-pid-of-the-last-executed-command-in-shell-script)

**El programa es un `shutdown`** decorado con distintas terminales para lograr efectos con las terminales de **xfce4** y animaciones **ASCII**.

El proyecto consta de los siguientes archivos:

> 1. **Launch.sh** un script inicial para lanzar las terminales formateadas
>    en tamaño, color y formato deseado.
> 2. Otros 3 scripts .sh que solo tienen la función de aportar efectos decorativos.
> 3. **app.pid** Una memoria para almacenar y leer los valores **PID**.
> 4. **shutdown.sh** Un último script que automatiza y solo pide un valor en minutos para programar un apagado del sistema.

Para lograr mi objetivo he declarado las siguientes líneas:

```
#!/bin/bash

#
# launch.sh
#

###############
#    SCRIPT
###############

#blink
exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator --geometry 48x20+720+260 --hide-scrollbar --hide-borders --hide-toolbar --color-bg="rgba(225,225,225,1)"  -e="sleep 0.3"


#Background
exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator --geometry 48x20+720+260 -T="Shutdown Click" --hide-scrollbar --hide-borders --hide-toolbar --color-bg="rgba(0,0,0,0)" -e="clear" -H &
echo $! > /home/emakt/Projectes/shutdowncli/app.pid
sleep 0.5

#Barinfo
exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator --geometry 48x4+720+260 -T="Shutdown Click" --hide-scrollbar --hide-borders --hide-toolbar --color-bg="rgba(0,0,0,0)" -e="/home/emakt/Projectes/shutdowncli/barinfo.sh" -H &
echo $! >> /home/emakt/Projectes/shutdowncli/app.pid


#Logo
exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator --geometry 48x6+720+338 -T="Shutdown Click" --hide-scrollbar --hide-borders --hide-toolbar --color-bg="rgba(0,0,0,0)" -e="/home/emakt/Projectes/shutdowncli/logo.sh" -H &
echo $! >> /home/emakt/Projectes/shutdowncli/app.pid


sleep 0.5

#shutdown
exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator --geometry 48x10+720+454 -T="Shutdown Click" --hide-scrollbar --hide-borders --hide-toolbar --color-bg="rgba(0,0,0,0)" -e="/home/emakt/Projectes/shutdowncli//shutdown.sh" -H &
echo $! >> /home/emakt/Projectes/shutdowncli/app.pid
```

Como podéis ver, una vez ejecutada una nueva terminal formateada:

```
exo-open --launch TerminalEmulator --geometry 48x4+720+260 -T="Shutdown Click" --hide-scrollbar --hide-borders --hide-toolbar --color-bg="rgba(0,0,0,0)" -e="/home/emakt/Projectes/shutdowncli/barinfo.sh" -H
```

Seguidamente le pido que me imprima el valor PID a nuestra memoria **app.pid**.

> `&`<-- Esta al final de la linea anterior  al lado derecho de de `-H`
>
> echo $! >> /home/emakt/Projectes/shutdowncli/app.pid

*Con esto obtenemos el **PID** *"supuesta-mente"* de los nuevos procesos ejecutados por launch y los tendremos guardados en el archivo app.pid*

*"Para asegurarnos que cada vez que lanzamos el script launch se borran los valores de PID anteriores, en el primer echo $! le declaramos con > en vez de >> para asi sobrescribir por completo el archivo."*

Finalmente,la última terminal, ejecuta el programa **shutdown.sh** y al finalizar la declaración utilizo un bucle `while` para leer los valores PID de nuestra memoria **app.pid** y ejecutar `kill` al número **PID** devuelto por la variable `line`:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
  kill -9 $line
done < /home/emakt/Projectes/shutdowncli/app.pid
```

**Este es el resultado:** https://ibb.co/w0fKXtR

¿Alguna idea de por qué sucede esto?

En esta última imagen podéis observar como al lanzar las terminales se aguarda un supuesto valor PID, que al relanzar el script varias veces da un numero único y no repetido. El error marcado en la terminal que ejecuta el script shutdown.sh y el propio código de este.

No estoy muy seguro de si estoy fallando en copiar los valores **PID** erróneos, o no comprendo bien cómo funciona **kill**, o por qué no, estoy ignorando algo que desconozco.

¿Puede que exista un modo mejor de hacer esta función?

> Podéis disfrutar de la primera versión plenamente funcional aquí:
> **[github shutdownclick](https://github.com/emakt/shutdownclick)**
>
> Dejo también por aquí este repositorio con esta nueva versión por si
> queréis probar con los archivos directamente **[aquí](https://github.com/emakt/Santander)**. RECORDAD cambiar todas las rutas de los ficheros.

Comment: Y si en lugar de usar kill utilizas `killall` ? En este caso en lugar de utilizar el pid del proceso puedes utilizar el nombre del programa ejecutado. En tu caso sería algo como `killall -9 exo-open` y así no tienes que buscar los pids...

Comment: @Jakala Faltaría entonces una manera de filtrar el valor real PID de esas 4 terminales.

No queremos por error cerrar otra terminal de trabajo, por ejemplo, aun asi, me da la idea de usar diferentes emuladores de terminal y dejar uno en concreto para estos rescripto ágiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución alternativa sin tener que usar **kill** ni guardar el valor **PID** es cambiando la memoria **app.pid** por una memoria simple tipo **memoria.txt**

*Necesitamos declarar las siguientes lineas:*

**1. Launch.sh**

> En el lanzador para resetear nuestra memoria declararemos en la primera linea:
>
> ```
> echo "0" > /home/usuario/Proyecto/memoria.txt
> ```

Seguidamente debemos saber cual sera el script principal que controle y sobrescriba la memoria y los pasivos que se mantendrán en bucle leyendo el valor de la memoria.

**2. Terminales_Pasivas.sh**

> Las terminales pasivas, podemos capturarlas con un bucle infinito hasta que la memoria se actualice a "1". Para ello declaramos al final del script las siguientes lineas:
>
> ```
> VAR=5
> while [ $VAR -le 30 ]
> do
> CONTROL=$(($(cat /home/emakt/Labscript/2-terminals-1-final/mem.txt)))
>
>
>  if [[ $CONTROL -eq 1 ]];then
>   break
>  fi
>  clear
> done
> ```

**3. Terminal_Activa.sh**

> En el script dominante, cuando termine todas sus funciones, declaramos
> la siguiente linea para sobrescribir la memoria a 1
>
> ```
> echo "1" > /home/emakt/Labscript/2-terminals-1-final/memoria.txt
> ```

Dejo [**aqui**](https://github.com/emakt/2terminales-1final) un repositorio con lo basico y funcional como template.

Podéis ver el resultado final [**aqui**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEn0_TmwBWw&ab_channel=Ericsama90)